# Pandas - how to remove rows with nulls based on one column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

```
|    A     |       B        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Cell 1   | np.nan         |
| Cell 2   | np.nan         |
| np.nan   | Cell 3         |
| Cell 4   | Cell 4         |
```

For example, I need to delete those rows where np.nan is present in table B

My code #1:

```
df = df[df['B'] != np.nan]
```

My code #2:

```
df = df.drop(df[
        df['B']
     ].index)
```

Comment: Use ‘df.dropna(subset=‘B’)’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will drop your nulls:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=‘B’)
```